# post request with flask-socketio cannot connect to proxy

Tags: python-requests, flask-socketio

I've tested my code in an environment(win10) with proxy settings, I didn't have to specify proxy settings and it works with only flask, but then when I start with sockio.run, it throws me the error :

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='notify-api.line.me', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/notify?message=12345 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))

I have no idea why is this happening, I tried adding http and https proxies into the requests parameter, setting cors_allowed_origins='*', still doesn't work.
Am I missing some headers to make it work? And why does it work without socketio?

```
import flask
import requests
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from engineio.async_drivers import gevent

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + 'qajyC1fFTqsabb3cTbnk5zCqDjRspZkDQwPPmeNbJCx', 
        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  
    payload = {'message': '12345'}
    r = requests.post("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", headers = headers, params = payload)
    return "12345"

socketio.run(app,host='10.110.50.51', port=8080)
```

Adding proxy to request doesn't work too

```
http_proxy  = "http://10.xx.xxx.xxx:8080"
https_proxy  = "https://10.xx.xxx.xxx:8080"

proxyDict = { 
      "http"  : http_proxy,
      "https"  : https_proxy, 
    }

headers = {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + 
'qajyC1fFTqsabb3cTbnk5zCqDjRspZkDQwPPmeNbJCx', 
"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

payload = {'message': '12345'}
r = requests.post("https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify", headers= headers, params = payload, proxies=proxyDict)

return "12345"
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like it's the problem with urllib3 package,
changing the proxy https to http solved my problem

```
http_proxy  = "http://10.xx.xx.xxx:8080"
https_proxy  = "http://10.xx.xx.xxx:8080"
```

The https_proxy goes through http instead of https and establish handshake!!

But I'm still confused why this problem only appears when using socketio running the app